# Measuring cannibalisation of category sales from the introducing of more brands/products

Tags: regression, machine-learning, forecasting, econometrics

A retail company has traditional brick-and-mortar stores of varying sizes and assortments and a webshop with a considerably larger assortment.

I am interested in a method for measuring how the introduction of more brands to the assortment cannibalises the sales from other brands within the same category. Most of these brands are only added to the online assortment, but some are later added to some of the brick-and-mortar stores as well (effectively bumping some other brand or product line).

To make the problem a bit simpler we could look at a brand, call it Brand A, that was only launched online and not made available in brick-and-mortar stores. Let's just say it was introduced 12 months ago.

One idea would be to model the category sales as if Brand A was never launched, essentially "forecasting" the category sales since the launch, for example as a regression problem with machine learning. The idea here would be to have input variables capturing, most importantly, time and promotions, and others. By comparing the predicted category sales with the actual ones (minus the sales of Brand A), we could calculate a kind of "cannibalisation rate".

However, one weakness with this approach is that some promotions have limited space, so to speak. For example, promotional emails can't be too long, so by promoting brand A, it means there is some other brand that isn't being promoted. There is no way I can counterfactually know if another brand would have been promoted had brand A not been launched in the first place. But I might be able to estimate the required feature by looking at the number of products historically being promoted on a given date etc.

**I would be very interested to hear any thoughts on the above approach or if there are any other approaches I should try.**

Minimally viable solutions that can be implemented with Python are preferred.

I will say, I have *only* been tasked with measuring how much Brand A cannibalises sales from the remaining category. I have not been tasked with determining which other brands or products Brand A cannibalises nor with determining the reasons for why Brand A cannibalises at all, but both those problems would be of interest, too.

**Note:** The company is launching new brands because they've assumed the uplift and recruitment of new customers etc. outweigh the "cost" in terms of the cannibalisation of existing brands and products. I guess they are interested in determining if their assumption is true (otherwise, it's a bad business strategy and they need to reconsider)

**Edit 2023-03-10:** From the comments below, I have gathered that the problem can be rather complex depending on the business environment. I am adding some context regarding the business environment here:

- the products are beauty and health products. Think face creams, makeup, perfumes, nutritional supplements etc. Many of these types of products are re-purchased but nowhere nearly as often as toilet paper (mentioned in the comments). I would expect high cannibalisation in the perfume category but these are also bought very infrequently and hence difficult to analyse.

Comment: I think your approach sounds sensible. It's quite similar to many agreed methods for this sort of analysis that you may want to checkout: differences in differences method (there's probably a python package that will do this), the R causalImpact package. The downside you describe is exactly a problem with many of these methods.

Comment: Close-voters: I believe this question is completely on-topic here, and have accordingly voted to leave it open. It's a *hard* question, though, because of all the influencing factors. There is the selection bias alluded to in the last paragraph. You may have different price points of the different brands, and introducing new products that address the same market as existing products *at a different price point* may better be seen as customer segmentation than as cannibalization. Seasonality may have an impact. And so forth. It will be hard to draw any conclusions with confidence.

Comment: @stephan-kolassa: Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by "customer segmentation" in this setting? By introducing similar products to existing ones at a very different price point, some existing customers might switch from one to the other, but it could potentially also win a whole new customer segment. On the whole, it could mean that the introduction of the products cannibalised sales from some other products, but the category as a whole grew because of it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you introduce a new product variant (whether at a new price point, or just any other variation, say a new yogurt flavor), you will likely attract some new customers, or have some existing customers buy more product altogether - but some of your old customers will likely also *switch* from the existing products to the new one. So to a degree, you have cannibalization. It's easier to analyze effects if you have customer-level data and repeat purchases, because then you can see who used to buy variant A and now buys variant B. For rare or one-time purchases, analysis is harder.

Comment: @stephan: What would you do differently if you had customer-level data for some customers (for the customers who did not check out as "guest". All "guests" would obviously my indistinguishable from each other)?

Comment: I would look at customers' shopping history: among all the customers that used to buy the potentially cannibalized original product, how many bought the new one and did not switch back, and how many tried the old one and did switch back? However, for this kind of analysis to be worth anything, you really need something that is bought very frequently, think toilet paper. It really depends very much on your assortment. You need to understand the business environment for your analysis: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/2406/2853